Issue with Redirection to wp-signup on Multisite Network using Local by flywheel
I recently started using Local by Flywheel for a WordPress multisite network and encountered a consistent redirection issue.
Whenever I access the wp-admin dashboard of a newly created subsite (e.g., sub-site.site.local/wp-admin) or even the main site, I am immediately redirected to the main site’s wp-signup page (site.local/wp-signup). Interestingly, appending a trailing slash to the URL (e.g., site.local/wp-admin/) resolves the issue, the issue only happens when I’m not logged in.
Thanks In Advance
Steps can be taken to replicate the issue
Create a New WordPress Multisite Project:

Set up a new WordPress project in Local, enabling the multisite feature with subdomains.
Access the Admin Dashboard:
Open a private browsing window.
Navigate to the URL yourdomain.local/wp-admin without including a trailing slash at the end.

System Details
Local Version:
Version 9.0.2+6676
Operating System (OS) and OS version:
Windows 11
Steps I’ve tried to resolve the issue include:

Creating a new project without any plugins, which resulted in the same redirection behavior.
Implementing a mu-plugin to override the redirection without success.
Switching the server from Nginx to Apache and modifying rewrite rules in the .htaccess file, but the problem persisted.
Could you please assist me in resolving this redirection issue? Thank you for your help!

